# Let A, B and C be three propositions. Give the truth table of the compound proposition...

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

please help me with the following exercise. I can do it with A and B but the addition of C has confused me and I do not know how to advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a truth table with reference collumns:

```
A B
T T
T F
F T
F F
```

You will have all possible combinations for A, B and C i.e.

```
A B C
T T T
T T F
T F T
T F F
F T T
F T F
F F T
F F F
```

Now you just need to fill in What your formula equal one each of these rows. Take one term at a time and it will be doable. Thus start with $A \Leftrightarrow B$, then do $B\Leftrightarrow C$ then use this to get $(A \Leftrightarrow B)\wedge (B \Leftrightarrow  C)$.

Can you do this?

Comment: I was able to do it, thank you very much!